# Using the same Excepts in different programs

Tags: python, exception

I have a bunch of  classes that all use the same module Errors.py where I defined my custom Exceptions with classes like:

```
class Errors(Exception):

  class funcUnicodeError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, param, err):
      self.err = err
      self.param = param
      self.msg = 'ERROR : Failed to decode PARAM: ' + param  
      self.code = 20
```

All these classes are re-used in different programs where i end up having a long list of except clauses at the end of the main function. It's all good except that these excepts are the same for different program, and i have to maintain it at different places.

Is there a way to stack these except clauses somewhere in order to have a single unique call to it in different programs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code

```
try:
   # do something
except Error1:
   # except clause 1
except Error2:
   # except clause 2
... # long list of except clauses
finally:
    # do something
```

is equivalent to

```
def main():
    # do something

def run(main_func):
    try:
        main_func()
    except Error1:
        # except clause 1
    except Error2:
        # except clause 2

    ... # long list of except clauses
    finally:
        # do something

run(main)
```

Now you can outsource the function `run` into a module and you can reuse it several times in different programs.

Answer (score 0):

If your exceptions are generic enough that multiple unrelated programs can share the same exception stack, you probably should try using the built-in exception classes (e.g. ValueError, TypeError, etc).

Comment: I need custom return codes so even for standard exceptions i wrap them with my own. But most of the times these are special errors.